# Opción de lista desplegable cambia estado de botón

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tengo un html con angularjs el cual me lista unas tuplas de una consulta, tengo una lista desplegable que se llama "tipificación" y un check con una palanca, la cual se debe de cambiar a "SI" cuando la opción de la lista es "OK", lo hago llamando una función que llame palanca() que esta en el JS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que se presenta es que solo me aplica para la primer tupla, para las demas no.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi HTML desde donde invoco la funcion palanca():

```
                                    <tr ng-repeat="data in contingenciasTV track by $index" ng-class="{'resaltado15min': data.horagestion <= quinceminutos[indice]}" >
                                        <td><center><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.bloqueo"
                                            name="bloqueo"
                                            id="bloqueo"
                                            ng-change="marcarEngestion(data)"></center></td>
                                            <td>{{data.logincontingencia}}</td>
                                            <td><span ng-class="{'label label-danger': data.engestion == 1}">{{data.pedido}}</span></td>
                                            <td>{{data.macEntra}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.macSale}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.paquetes}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.perfil}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.ciudad}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.proceso}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.accion}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.horagestion}}</td>   
                                            <td>{{data.producto}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.tipoEquipo}}</td>
                                            <td>{{data.remite}}</td>

                                            <td><select ng-model="data.tipificacion" class="btn btn-default btn-xs grupo-select" name="tipificacion" style="width:100px" id="tipificacion" onchange="palanca()"> 
                                            <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
                                            <option value="Rechazado por posible fraude">Rechazado por posible fraude</option>
                                            <option value="Rechazado por mal ingreso">Rechazado por mal ingreso</option>
                                            <option value="Duplicado">Duplicado</option>
                                            <option value="Error de despacho(faltó gestión)">Error de despacho(faltó gestión)</option>
                                            <option value="Reenvio Falla">Reenvio Falla</option>
                                            <option value="Error del Sistema">Error del Sistema</option>
                                                </select></td>
                                            <td>
```

Y este es el JS con la funciona palanca:

```
function palanca()
```

{

```
    var valortipificacion=document.getElementById("tipificacion").value;

    if(valortipificacion=="Ok")
    {
       document.getElementById("acepta").checked=true;
    } 
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("acepta").checked=false;
    }
```

}

Saludos cordiales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te puse un ejemplo aquí.

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).controller('MyCntrl', function($scope) {
   var vm = this;

   $scope.friends = [
    { name:'John', tipificacion:'', acepta: false },
    { name:'Mary', tipificacion:'', acepta: false  },
    { name:'Peter', tipificacion:'', acepta: false }
  ];

   vm.palanca = function( obj ) {
     if ( obj.tipificacion == 'Ok' ) {
        obj.acepta = true;
     } else {
        obj.acepta = false;
     }
   }; });
```

Y el HTML quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCntrl as vm"><div ng-repeat="person in friends" ><input type="checkbox" ng-model="person.acepta" />    
<select ng-model="person.tipificacion" name="tipificacion" ng-change="vm.palanca( person )" >
    <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
    <option value="Rechazado por posible fraude">Rechazado por posible fraude</option>
    <option value="Rechazado por mal ingreso">Rechazado por mal ingreso</option>
    <option value="Duplicado">Duplicado</option>
    <option value="Error de despacho(faltó gestión)">Error de despacho(faltó gestión)</option>
    <option value="Reenvio Falla">Reenvio Falla</option>
    <option value="Error del Sistema">Error del Sistema</option> </select> </div></div>
```

Te dejo el enlace con el ejemplo para que puedas verlo en acción.

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/872yuwr0/1)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/125241)

Comment: Gracias por la observación.

Comment: @RobertoMunguia gracias por el ejemplo me sirvió para orientarme con lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

No funciona porque para cambiar el check, estas obteniendo el elemento por el ID, y como lo tienes en un repeat, el ID es el mismo para todos los elemento, el ID debe ser único por elemento.

Hay varias soluciones.

1. Concatenar el nombre del ID con el index ($index) del repeat.

```html
<td><select ng-model="data.tipificacion" class="btn btn-default btn-xs grupo-select" name="{{ $index }}tipificacion" style="width:100px" id="tipificacion" onchange="palanca( $index )"> 
                                            <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
                                            <option value="Rechazado por posible fraude">Rechazado por posible fraude</option>
                                            <option value="Rechazado por mal ingreso">Rechazado por mal ingreso</option>
                                            <option value="Duplicado">Duplicado</option>
                                            <option value="Error de despacho(faltó gestión)">Error de despacho(faltó gestión)</option>
                                            <option value="Reenvio Falla">Reenvio Falla</option>
                                            <option value="Error del Sistema">Error del Sistema</option>
                                                </select></td>
                                            <td>
```

Y tu metodo Palanca quedaria así:

```js
function palanca( numero )
{

    var id = numero;
    var valortipificacion=document.getElementById(id + "tipificacion").value;

    if(valortipificacion=="Ok")
    {
       document.getElementById("acepta").checked=true;
    } 
    else
    {
       document.getElementById("acepta").checked=false;
    }
}
```

Esto puede funcionar pero no te lo recomiendo.

Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

2. En tu funcion palanca() pedir el objeto ( obj ) y que ese objeto contenga una propiedad boleana para cambiar de verdadero a falso, y agregarlo hacer el binding con el elemento por medio de ng-model.

```js
function palanca( obj )
{

    if(valortipificacion=="Ok")
    {
       obj.check = true;
    } 
    else
    {
       obj.check = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, el objeto que debo pedir es del check?

Comment: No, le debes enviar el objeto que se encuentra en esta lista contingenciasTV, como lo tienes en tu repeat se lo enviarias de la siguiente manera  onchange="palanca( data )".

Comment: perfecto, la duda ahora es como cambio a true o false el obj.check como está ahí no me funciona?

Comment: Lo harias mas o menos como este checkbox que tienes, <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.bloqueo" > y en la funcion palanca obj.bloqueo = true.

Comment: mira como lo estoy haciendo pero no me funciona.

Comment: te puse un ejemplo aqui. https://jsfiddle.net/872yuwr0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Este es el Check:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="flipswitch" style="width:50px"
        ng-model="data.acepta" 
        name="acepta"
        id="acepta"
        ng-change="changeStatus(data)">
```

Y este es el JS con la función palanca:

```
function palanca(selectObject)
```

{

```
       var valortipificacion=selectObject.value;
    if(valortipificacion=="Ok")
    {

      obj.acepta = true;


    } 
    else
    {

       obj.acepta = false;


    }
```

}